# How to solve this Rails Active Record erorr: undefined method `to_sym' for #<Arel::Attributes::Attribute:...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We're using Ruby on Rails (Active Record with MySQL database).

We're getting this mysterious error:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for #<Arel::Attributes::Attribute:0x007f82e4088248>
```

I look at our Ruby code and tried it in IRB, it seems to work with Rails/ActiveRecord.

So what does the error message above mean and how can we fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace here as well?

Comment: Here it is, not sure how much it helps    app/views/home/_top_collectors.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_home__top_collectors_html_erb___1114436438966347956_69885225174440'
    app/views/home/_top_collectors.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_home__top_collectors_html_erb___1114436438966347956_69885225174440'
    app/views/home/index.html.erb:45:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb__2079745407266393088_69885433760820'

Comment: Sorry to bother, but what's in your _top_collectors.html.erb file? At least the code around where it crashes? I would bet on some serialization (maybe a to_json call) screws with to_sym...

Answer (score 1):

The `to_sym` method converts a string into a symbol. ie: `"example".to_sym` becomes `:example`
Somewhere in your code, you are passing a object into a method that expects a symbol, and ruby can't find the appropriate symbol to replace the object with. Your going to have to look at the stack trace or some other means to find where this occurs.

Comment: I know what to_sym does.  I think the key is Arel here.  Interestingly, I tried those ruby code in Rails console and they work.  So I don't know why they break on the page.

Comment: I can't tell you since I can't see your code. From the stack trace you  posted in your comment above it looks like something in your `_top_colectors.html.erb` file.